# Prove $ u \cdot (u \times (\nabla \times u)) = 0 $

Tags: vectors

Prove $$ u \cdot (u \times (\nabla \times u)) = 0 $$

Where '$u$' is a 3D-velocity vector.

I came across this for a proof for converting Euler's Equation to the Bernoulli expression for a steady-state, in compressible fluid.

Anyone know why this is the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simplicity, call ${\bf v} = \nabla \times {\bf u}$. The idea is that ${\bf u} \times {\bf v}$ is perpendicular to both ${\bf u}$ and ${\bf v}$, so that

$$
{\bf u} \cdot({\bf u} \times {\bf v}) = 0
$$

Comment: So would $\vec{u}\cdot(\vec{u}\times\vec{v}) = 0$ in general?

Comment: @SolomonUcko Correct!